# Why does Kentico allow both Allow and Deny page permission to be checked at the same time

Tags: kentico

What is the reason behind allowing both Allow and Deny permission to be checked at the same time on a page?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the reason why, but I am pretty sure Deny always wins.

Comment: Correct, deny will ALWAYS win.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this page permission set today and seems like I found the answer to my question. Allow permission may be inherited from the parent, but a role might explicitly be denied to override the inheritance.

[image]